How can I shift a column in a dataframe x times into an array, apply a function, and create a new column?
I am having a hard time understanding how I can better improve this code:
from datetime import datetime

import math
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def trending(row, label, amt, prepend = False, postpend = False, reverse = True):
    arr = []

    if prepend:
        arr.append(row[label])

    for i in range(amt):
        arr.append(row[f'{label}_{i}'])

    if postpend:
        arr.append(row[label])

    if reverse:
        arr.reverse()

    if any(x == None or math.isnan(x) for x in arr):
        return 0

    return slope(arr)

def slope(arr):
    if len(arr) <= 1:
        return 0
    coeffs = np.polyfit(range(len(arr)), arr, 1)
    slope = coeffs[-2]
    return float(slope)

def trends(df):
    start = datetime.now()

    look_back = 5

    for i in range(look_back):
        j = i + 1
        df2 = df[['close', 'pvi', 'nvi', 'smi', 'roc', 'macd', 'histogram', 'percent_b', 'height']]
        df2 = df2.add_suffix(f'_{i}')
        df2 = df2.shift(j)
        df = pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1)

    def close_trend(row):
        return trending(row, 'close', look_back, True, False)

    def pvi_trend(row):
        return trending(row, 'pvi', look_back, True, False)

    def nvi_trend(row):
        return trending(row, 'nvi', look_back, True, False)

    def smi_trend(row):
        return trending(row, 'smi', look_back, True, False)

    def macd_trend(row):
        return trending(row, 'macd', look_back, True, False)

    def roc_trend(row):
        return trending(row, 'roc', look_back, True, False)

    def histogram_trend(row):
        return trending(row, 'histogram', look_back, True, False)

    def percent_b_trend(row):
        return trending(row, 'percent_b', look_back, True, False)

    def height_trend(row):
        return trending(row, 'height', look_back, True, False)
    
    df['close_trend'] = df.apply(close_trend, axis=1)
    df['pvi_trend'] = df.apply(pvi_trend, axis=1)
    df['nvi_trend'] = df.apply(nvi_trend, axis=1)
    df['smi_trend'] = df.apply(smi_trend, axis=1)
    df['macd_trend'] = df.apply(macd_trend, axis=1)
    df['roc_trend'] = df.apply(roc_trend, axis=1)
    df['histogram_trend'] = df.apply(histogram_trend, axis=1)
    df['percent_b_trend'] = df.apply(percent_b_trend, axis=1)
    df['height_trend'] = df.apply(height_trend, axis=1)

    print(f'Trends function took {datetime.now() - start}')

    return df

data = []

for i in range(10000):
    data.append([545.9, 0.3333398862,   0.01673619117,  0.2111060119,   55.95725508,    1.100447539,    0.8652411735,   0.8219623901,   1.808441041,    46.79554862])

columns = ['close', 'macd', 'histogram', 'roc', 'rsi', 'pvi', 'nvi', 'percent_b', 'height', 'smi']

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns, data=data)

df = trends(df)

print(df)

It works, but it is awfully slow. I have a dataframe without about 10k rows and it takes about 30s. Basically, what I am trying to accomplish is this:

Shift the "trend columns" x number of times so each row has the x number of previous values
Take those values + the current rows value and find the slope
Set the slope to a "trending" column


Why go through a 1-degree polynomial fit?  Wouldn't (n[4]-n[0])/5 give you the same result?

@TimRoberts not sure about this python function, but that intuitevely should not be equivalent. Image four points (no 0,1,2,4) on a constant line, eg. y=2  and just n[3] outlier high in the sky. Result of interpolation should not be a1=0 as (n[4]-n[0])/5 would suggest

@GrizzlyEnglish could you provide some minimal, reproducible example?

@TimRoberts Not going to pretend to be that great a math, but yeah based on searching that seemed the best to get "trend" like slope. EDIT: That code is stolen from another SO question to be honest

@dankal444  Yes! Sorry, I updated the code to be runnable. It doesn't seem slow with 20 rows but it does not scale well, didn't want to hard code 10k rows haha

Apologies. Dumb mistake, didn't need real data so I just added loop and added the same bar information. This shows the terrible performance

@GrizzlyEnglish I'm not sure... on what hardware you're running the code? Running the example takes ~4seconds on my computer (amd 5700x)

@AndrejKesely Interesting. I have a i9-9900k. Running the script I get a tiny bump in cpu utilization but not much... Not sure. EDIT: Oh well, I dropped the debugger and it improved performance a lot. Might just roll with that. Thanks for the info!

You can achieve huge speed-up (200-300x) by applying polyfit to whole dataframe instead of doing it row by row.
I added some code to check correctness, check yourself and remove  afterwards.
def trending_vectorized(df, label, amt, prepend=False, postpend=False, reverse=True):
    arr = []

    if prepend:
        arr.append(df[label])

    for i in range(amt):
        arr.append(df[f'{label}_{i}'])

    if postpend:
        arr.append(df[label])

    if reverse:
        arr.reverse()

    arr = np.vstack(arr)
    poly_coeffs = np.polyfit(np.arange(len(arr)), np.vstack(arr), 1)
    poly_coeffs[np.isnan(poly_coeffs)] = 0  # possible speed-up: insert zeros where needed
    return poly_coeffs[0, :]  # slope only

def trends(df):
    start = datetime.now()

    look_back = 5

    for i in range(look_back):
        j = i + 1
        df2 = df[['close', 'pvi', 'nvi', 'smi', 'roc', 'macd', 'histogram', 'percent_b', 'height']]
        df2 = df2.add_suffix(f'_{i}')
        df2 = df2.shift(j)
        df = pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1)

    def close_trend(row):
        return trending(row, 'close', look_back, True, False)

    def pvi_trend(row):
        return trending(row, 'pvi', look_back, True, False)

    def nvi_trend(row):
        return trending(row, 'nvi', look_back, True, False)

    def smi_trend(row):
        return trending(row, 'smi', look_back, True, False)

    def macd_trend(row):
        return trending(row, 'macd', look_back, True, False)

    def roc_trend(row):
        return trending(row, 'roc', look_back, True, False)

    def histogram_trend(row):
        return trending(row, 'histogram', look_back, True, False)

    def percent_b_trend(row):
        return trending(row, 'percent_b', look_back, True, False)

    def height_trend(row):
        return trending(row, 'height', look_back, True, False)

    df['close_trend'] = df.apply(close_trend, axis=1)
    df['pvi_trend'] = df.apply(pvi_trend, axis=1)
    df['nvi_trend'] = df.apply(nvi_trend, axis=1)
    df['smi_trend'] = df.apply(smi_trend, axis=1)
    df['macd_trend'] = df.apply(macd_trend, axis=1)
    df['roc_trend'] = df.apply(roc_trend, axis=1)
    df['histogram_trend'] = df.apply(histogram_trend, axis=1)
    df['percent_b_trend'] = df.apply(percent_b_trend, axis=1)
    df['height_trend'] = df.apply(height_trend, axis=1)

    df['close_trend2'] = trending_vectorized(df, 'close', look_back, True, False)
    df['pvi_trend2'] = trending_vectorized(df, 'pvi', look_back, True, False)
    df['nvi_trend2'] = trending_vectorized(df, 'nvi', look_back, True, False)
    df['smi_trend2'] = trending_vectorized(df, 'smi', look_back, True, False)
    df['macd_trend2'] = trending_vectorized(df, 'macd', look_back, True, False)
    df['roc_trend2'] = trending_vectorized(df, 'roc', look_back, True, False)
    df['histogram_trend2'] = trending_vectorized(df, 'histogram', look_back, True, False)
    df['percent_b_trend2'] = trending_vectorized(df, 'percent_b', look_back, True, False)
    df['height_trend2'] = trending_vectorized(df, 'height', look_back, True, False)

    assert np.allclose(df['close_trend'], df['close_trend2'])
    assert np.allclose(df['pvi_trend'], df['pvi_trend2'])
    assert np.allclose(df['nvi_trend'], df['nvi_trend2'])
    assert np.allclose(df['smi_trend'], df['smi_trend2'])
    assert np.allclose(df['macd_trend'], df['macd_trend2'])
    assert np.allclose(df['roc_trend'], df['roc_trend2'])
    assert np.allclose(df['histogram_trend'], df['histogram_trend2'])
    assert np.allclose(df['percent_b_trend'], df['percent_b_trend2'])
    assert np.allclose(df['height_trend'], df['height_trend2'])
    print(f'Trends function took {datetime.now() - start}')

    return df

Noted you liked clean code, so bonus - cleaned function:
def trends2(df):
    col_names = ['close', 'pvi', 'nvi', 'smi', 'macd', 'roc', 'histogram', 'percent_b', 'height']
    look_back = 5
    for i in range(look_back):
        j = i + 1
        df2 = df[col_names]
        df2 = df2.add_suffix(f'_{i}')
        df2 = df2.shift(j)
        df = pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1)

    for col_name in col_names:
        df[f'{col_name}_trend'] = trending_vectorized(df, col_name, look_back, True, False)

    return df


Wow thank you! An actual wizard. I had a feeling there was a way to not have to loop every single row I just have a hard time wrapping my brain around how to write dataframe code.

@GrizzlyEnglish On this site there are better wizards :) Whenever efficiency is important I advice switching from pandas to numpy array. Take a look at polars package too (more difficult but very fast pandas-like library)

There is not much we can do for speed since it depends essentially from the slope() function.
We can simplify the rest of the process skipping the creation  of shifted columns.
 df['close_trend'] = df['close'].rolling(look_back+1).apply(slope)


Awesome. Sure it doesn't help the performance but man is it cleaner code! Appreciate it
